# How to register new module in zend framework 2

Tags: php, oop, module, zend-framework2, xml-namespaces

I want to make my own module in zend framework2, I have tried this below code as per the doc. mentioned

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Album',
        'Photo',
    'SanAuth',
    'Newmodule',  // <- here is my newly added module name
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
```

But when I add this only one line code! my all working module gives blank result even which are working fine started giving blank result!
How can I come out from this ?

Answer (score 0):

What you did is enabling the Module. You should have created it first. 
Take a look [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/modules.html).
And you can use [ZFTool](https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool) for module managing (it saves you from the dull process).

It's normal to see a blank screen. There is an Exception being thrown which is probably saying that your module doesn't exist or something like that. Make sure you set `display_errors = On` in your php.ini, so you can debug in an easier manner.

Answer (score 0):

All you have done it tell Zend to start looking for a new module, but you have yet to create the module.

to create the module you need to add a folder with the same name under the ./module folder.

```
namespace ModuleName;

Class Module {

}
```

which is the minimum a module needs to load.